# Exec real world example

Tags: unix, exec

I am looking for a real world scenerio where using exec will be the only availble option ( The problem could not be solved if exec is not used)

I know what is exec and how it differs from fork, but still intrested in real world problem that enforce the use of exec command.

Comment: Dude, what language, what OS, etc? By 'exec' do you mean CEO of British Petroleum? Ask specific questions if you want helpful answers.

Comment: Loading another Unix binary from the current process is not *real world* enough? Do you think the Unix shell is a bad idea? What is the context of your question?

Comment: ...is this about the shell command called exec or the exec system call family (`man 3 exec`)?

Comment: @Matti does your shell have a fork call as well then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would a shell start another process, *without* using exec?

`fork()` (or, better `clone()` nowadays, on Linux) just says to duplicate a process. So then you have 2 copies of the same process.

`execve()` (and -le, -lp, -vp, -v friends) just says to replace the current process entirely with a new process. (keeping the fd's, but not much more)

So to fire another program, you must first `fork()` and then `exec()` in one of the resulting processes (which is normally the child process).

Comment: That's right, there is some kind of synergy between both syscalls. They usually are used together.